# Who receives contact form emails?

Tags: magento-1, forms

I am using the following contact form

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

When someone completes the form and sends it where will the contact message be sent to?

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Contacts**

Check email address in **Send Emails To** field. The data will be sent to this email address.
[image]